# Blackmagic UltraStudio 4k Extreme recording through SFP

Tags: live-recording, blackmagic

The [Blackmagic UltraStudio 4k Extreme](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/ultrastudio) has some [SFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver) ports.

Is it possible for that device to **record to a network location** like a NAS or SAN directly using a **fibre connection**?

Or is the fibre connection just used as another way to connect to a Mac or PC which would then do the recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [B&H details](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1137311-REG/blackmagic_design_bdlkulsr4kextr_ultrastudio_4k_extreme.html), the SFP cages are for 12G-SDI over fiber. They can only be used for baseband video I/O, not for an interface to a computer or network.